# Executing angularJS unit test in karma tool

Tags: angularjs

It was executing all test cases without any issues. i don't understand what happened suddenly.
when i execute the command **karma start karma.conf.js** it is not executing all test cases.
Result am getting is,
**Chrome 40.0.2214 (Windows 7): Executed 10 of 1517 (skipped 1507) SUCCESS (0.53 s
ecs / 0.134 secs)**

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One of my test files has,

```
ddescribe('my controller tests, ', function () {
```

this should be,

```
describe('my controller tests, ', function () {
```